# Confused by behavior of property setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, weak-references

*(this question probably needs a more descriptive title, feel free to improve it)*

I have a `UIView` subclass with a property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *label;
```

In an `initialize` method I have:

```
[self addSubview: (self.label = [UILabel new])];
```

I like the terseness of this, but I have questions how it works.

For one, I get a warning:

```
Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment
```

Warning aside, it actually seems to work. Is that because before the release machinery can run, the `addSubview:` re-retains it?

If I understand correctly, the `self.label = ...` code is just sugar for a `[self setLabel: ...]`. But if I override the property access with my own `setLabel:` implementation, its signature will be

```
- (void) setLabel: (UILabel*) label;
```

So the return value is **void**. But it's being fed into the the `addSubview:` send and working? So how does that work?

## Update

One of the things that frustrates doing a one liner here, is that `Objective-C` tend to eschew returning useful information from methods like `addSubview:` which is divergent from the `Smalltalk` influence which spawned Objective-C in the first place. In Smalltalk, it would be expected/common for the `addSubview:` method to return the added object. If this was the case, one could write these expressions as:

```
self.label = [self addSubview: [UILabel new]];
```

This would allow the strong/weak semantics to be happy. The `addSubview:` would do the strong retain before the it got to the weak `label` setter.

I fight this problem with both `subviews` and `recognizers`, so I thought I'd be clever, and write a `category` to do something like that (I inverted the receiver/argument so it would be easily distinguishable from an alternate addSubview: signature).

```
@interface UIView (UIView_Adding)
    - (UIView*) addedToView: (UIView*) superview;
@end

@interface UIGestureRecognizer (UIView_Adding)
    - (UIGestureRecognizer*) addedToView: (UIView*) view;
@end

@implementation UIView (UIView_Adding)
- (UIView*) addedToView: (UIView*) superview {
    [superview addSubview: self];
    return self;
}
@end

@implementation UIGestureRecognizer (UIView_Adding) 
- (UIGestureRecognizer*) addedToView: (UIView*) view {
    [view addGestureRecognizer: self];
    return self;
}
@end
```

Unfortunately, this just invokes the Law of Conservation of Ugly. I get rid of one kind of warning and get another. With that category included, I can now write:

```
self.label = [[UILabel new] addedToView: self];
```

But this generates a warning that `self.label` is meant to hold a specific subclass of `UIView`, namely a `UILabel` and the return type of `addedToView:` is `UIView'. I'm not aware of an Objective-C pseudo type which means *be the right darn subtype of this known super type to make property types happy*. :(

## Final Update

I discovered the `instancetype` type. By changing my category method signatures to return these types, everything just works. I'm new enough to `instancetype` to not know if I'm abusing something here, but I'm thrilled it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning comes from:

```
self.label = [UILabel new]
```

since your `label` property is `weak`.

You are correct that it ends up working because the label is retained by the call to `addSubview:`.

But if the label is ever removed from its superview, the `label` property will become `nil` and the label will be lost. So if there is any chance that the label will be removed but you want to keep a reference to the label (maybe to add it back later), then change your property to be `strong`.

You are also correct that `self.label =` is really just `[self setLabel:]`. The reason that this can be passed to `addSubview:` is due to the fact that an expression such as `x = y` has a value equal to the assignment.

So:

```
[self addSubview: (self.label = [UILabel new])];
```

if equivalent to:

```
UIView *view = (self.label = [UILabel new]);
[self addSubview:view];
```

Comment: There is also a time when it is not retained: between the two statements. This construct can not be relied on. But it is the usual case that subviews are only retained by their parent view which is why they are usually declared weak.

Comment: @Zaph Assuming you are talking about the last two lines in my answer, it can be relied on since the local variable `view` is `strong`.

Comment: Is the property not actually autoreleased, where it would only vanish after the runloop has finished the current cycle?

Comment: @ahwulf The property is declared as `weak`. Why would it be autoreleased?

Comment: I don't follow `...the fact that an expression such as x = y has a value equal to the assignment...`. Is that something the compiler adds to the code in addition to the `setLabel:` dispatch? Putting it in a temporary variable as you have, I'd just suspect that the `setLabel:` call stuffed `void` in the intermediate variable. Which wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, the compiler is doing two things here. Even though the `self.label = ` syntax is converted to a call to `[self setLabel:]` (which has no return value), the compiler knows that you used the assignment syntax. And in Objective-C (and C), an assignment expression has the value of the assignment so that value can be used.

Comment: Also, is there a way to tweak the code to remain a one liner, but to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Change the property to be `strong` instead of `weak`. But there is no need to keep it one line. It's harder to read and harder to debug.